# Why is my form not validating via jquery and why does jsfiddle show me an error`

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

my form isn´t validating and I don´t know why. I tried js fiddle and now there is an error:

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}

Here is the link to js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D65WY/1/

Comment: You should read the documentation for jsfiddle. For one thing, you don't put `<script>` tags in the JavaScript window. It's also necessary to include your validation plugin (probably; it's not part of jQuery proper, right?)

Comment: Also you only need to call `jQuery.noConflict()` once.

Comment: And why two times document ready event?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. You don't need `<script>` tags when posting in the JS window in jsFiddle.
2. The `validate` method in your code is undefined. Are you missing a plugin reference?
3. `jQuery.noConflict();` only needs to be called once.

Here's a working fiddle with your errors fixed and the validate plugin pulled from one of the demo pages: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/D65WY/3/

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your help. But where are the changes you have made. In your fiddle there are two noConflicts and only the validate plugin is pulled from another site. Is this the problem?

Comment: @DanielGorges, the fiddle was simply to get you started in the right direction and show you that you're code will work, given the right references. I suggest downloading a local copy of the `validate()` plugin, and following the suggestions in my answer. We're here to teach a person how to fish, not catch all the fish :)